# Seaching for bytes in a word finder

Tags: java

I'm working on a little program that search for words in a 100MB .txt file. I'm currently loading the file by:

```
Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

I'm seaching for the specific word using:

```
final static byte[] word = "this".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Since I wanted the method that was seaching for the word, to take the word as argument, I moved `.getBytes` into my method instead.

Suddenly i went from getting my result in 65ms to 133ms.

I tried other ways I could think of, but the best so far only reduced it to 105ms, which was referencing it from another class which called the word finder method.

Any idea why the drop in performance or might the 'byte' search be a bad idea for starters?

Comment: searching for substring in O(n): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm an algorithm often unknown

Comment: Im actually using that algorithm to seach in the bytes :)

Comment: To benchmark properly you'd need to call the method many times. If you're encoding the argument each time, instead of once when the class is loaded, it's going to take longer. It's difficult to predict the performance of code you can see. Near impossible to predict performance of code you can't see.

Comment: And maybe you should post a bit more code; I am not sure what exactly you mean with "moved .getBytes into my method". Which method?

Comment: why don't you use `char[]` or `int[]` to store chars, not bytes? For non-ascii text that would perform faster

Comment: To start with I was encoding it each time I called the search method, that took around +60ms in total for the method. I then encoded it in another method before I started the timer and referenced it staticly, but it still took +30ms.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I will try the char[] method and see how that goes :)

Comment: Does the search take ~100ms or the entire operation (including interaction with the filesystem)?